# Can I declare two protocols using the same associated type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have two protocols that define the same `associatedtype State: MyState`. One of the protocols has a variable of type the other protocol, so what I want to do is to pass an object of type `State` from one protocol to the other. However, this won't compile because `State` might not be the in the view than in the interactor, besides conforming to the same protocol. Any alternatives to this? Here I include a snippet that can run on a playground with what I want to do.

```
protocol MyState {}

protocol View {

    associatedtype State: MyState

    func renderState(state: State)
}

protocol Interactor {

    associatedtype CustomView: View
    associatedtype State: MyState

    var view: CustomView { get }
}

extension Interactor {

    func updateState(uiState: State) {
        view.renderState(state: uiState) // <---- error: cannot invoke 'renderState' with an argument list of type '(state: Self.State)'
    }
}
```

Comment: Your extension needs a `where State == CustomView.State` otherwise there isn't anything saying that the two states need to be the same type.

Comment: You don't need `associatedtype State: MyState` in `protocol Interactor` – declare the function as `func updateState(uiState: CustomView.State)` instead.

Comment: Adding the `where` clause fixed it! Thanks